# How to identify the anchor tag with data-href attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I had a series of anchor tags as following

```
    <a href="#" data-href=".60">CM</a>
```

I am trying to get this element using following code but i am not succeded.

```
    $("a[data-href=.60]").addClass("green");
```

suggest correct one

```
    var scatid=getUrlVars()["scatid"];

    $('a[data-href=".+scatid+"]').addClass("green");
```

if i replace variable at 60 it's not working, what is the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a special character in the attribute value, you need to enclose it in `""` like

```
var variable = '.60';
$('a[data-href="' + variable + '"]').addClass("green");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B8Gw2/)

Comment: Thank you, but i have to use variable at 60 how can i use it,

Comment: @SekharBabu at 60 or `.60`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[data-href=".'+scatid'+"]').addClass("green");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('href') == '.60'){
        $(this).addClass('green');
    }
});
```

or

```
 $('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('href') == '.' + scatid){
        $(this).addClass('green');
    }
 });
```